# Is it possible to modify the output of a macro in VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, build, macros

I'm using the [Custom Build Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730877(VS.80).aspx) feature in Visual Studio 2005, which allows to use macros such as `$(ConfigurationName)` in the XML .rules file.

I need to pass only a subset of `$(ConfigurationName)` as a parameter to my command-line tool:

If my target is named `DebugBuild`, I'd like the command to end up like `tool.exe -Debug`.

Is there a way to do this?
I thought about creating a [user-defined macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2t8ztwy(VS.80).aspx), but I don't know if they can contain more than plain text.
What I have in mind is to end up with something like this in my custom property pages:

Either

```
Tool Parameter: $(MyMacroWhichExtractsPartOfTheConfigurationName)
```

Or

```
Tool Parameter: ExtractorMethod( $(ConfigurationName) )
```

Sorry if this is not very clear, I can give more details if needed :)

Thanks!

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create a script (eg minsys bash or windows bat) which you run, and which translates the arguments to what you want, rather than trying to do it within VS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there are several places where I'd like to have this functionality available (output name, parameter to the compile/link steps, parameter to the post-build step...), so the script solution would make things a bit convoluted. I'd like to keep it simple, if at possible. Thanks!